# Can i use a SELECT statement to define a CHECK constraint?

Tags: sql-server, database, constants

In MS SQL server, can i use a SELECT statement to define a CHECK constraint? Say i have to work with two tables "Customer Master" and "Indian Customer" in ideal situation both tables are compleatly different, and are not interrelated in anyways. however they share the same database

```
Content of "Customer Master":
CustomerName (colomn): a, b, c, d, e
Branchlocation (colomn): IN, AU, IN, IN, UK

Content of "Indian Customer":
customerID (colomn): 1, 2, 3
CustomerName  (colomn): a, c, d
customer details (colomn): details1, details, details
.
.
.
```

In Table "Indian Customer" i want to put a constraint so that the users entring data in this table should not be able to enter customers that dont exist in "Customer Master" or whose branch location is not IN. also the tables are in the same project but are **NOT directly related** . In other words you can say Only indian customer from "Customer Master" should be in table "Indian Customer".

```
select CustomerName from "Customer Master"
where Branchlocation = 'IN'
```

the output of the above query should only be allowed in ["Indian Customer"].[CustomerName]

Comment: Please provide some concrete example. Select statement is used for retrieving data, Check is used for validating data. So I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Agree on that. Your example is not a check constraint, but a select filter. Maybe a book for SQL beginners is in lieu? Reading it may clean up some confusion. Voted to close - question is unclear.

Comment: @Tom Tom: Maybe if you read the question you might understand it. 'SELECT statement to define a CHECK' means to me using a subquery in the check clause.

Comment: Well, you may want to read a beginner SQL book.You mix up terms left and right. a qhere condition clause is not acheck constraint. Check constraints are there to check inserted / manipulated data confirms to the constraints, which makes zero sense in a select (as it does not change / update data). Use the right terms. Those who do not say what they mean, often do not mean what they say. Mastering some basic vocabulary is core to work in IT.

Comment: For you first constraint, what's wrong with creating a `FOREIGN KEY` from `[Indian Customer].CustomerName` to `[Customer Master].CustomerName`? Your second constraint doesn't make sense to me. The BranchLocation does not exist in the `[Indian Customer]` table.

Comment: Probably, I would rearrange the data so that Indian and non-Indian customers could be stored in different tables, and there would be a master view to list all the customers. The "Non-Indian Customer" table might want a check constraint that would prohibit adding customers with `Branchlocation = 'IN'`. Alternatively there could be a trigger that would move all the 'IN'-customers from "Non-Indian Customer" to "Indian Customer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add some additional constraints and superkeys, and get what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerMaster (
     CustomerName varchar(100) not null,
     LocationCode char(2) not null,
     constraint PK_CustomerMaster PRIMARY KEY (CustomerName),
     constraint UQ_CustomerMaster_Location UNIQUE (CustomerName,LocationCode), /* <-- Superkey here */
     constraint CK_CustomerMaster_Locations CHECK (
         LocationCode in ('IN','UK','AU')
)

CREATE TABLE IndianCustomer (
     CustomerID int not null,
     CustomerName varchar(100) not null,
     CustomerDetails varchar(max) not null,
     LocationCode as 'IN' persisted,
     constraint FK_IndianCustomer_CustomerMaster FOREIGN KEY (CustomerName,LocationCode) references CustomerMaster (CustomerName,LocationCode)
)
```

By having LocationCode as a computed column in IndianCustomer, and having the foreign key against the superkey, you're ensuring the data matches.

You can define an additional FK constraint just for CustomerName -> CustomerName, this can prove useful in some circumstances.

---

Or, to put it another way - there is *one*, highly stylised way to construct a constraint based on a "select" statement - and that is a FOREIGN KEY. But you sometimes have to add additional information (such as super keys, computed columns) to satisfy additional filtering requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Normally 3 ways

First way, best, using DRI

- define an extra column Branchlocation in "Indian Customer"
- add a CHECK CONSTRAINT to limit it to "IN"
- add a unique constraint on "Customer Master" for CustomerName/ID, Branchlocation
- foreign key on both CustomerName/ID, Branchlocation from "Indian Customer" to "Customer Master"

This works cleanly without code or triggers

Edit: as per Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer

Second way, OK, triggers

- On insert or update of "Indian Customer", check Customer Master

Third way, not so good, use a function

- A check constraint on "Indian Customer" uses a function to hide the SELECT

[This is not safe for concurrency and is not guaranteed to work](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx)

Comment: Second way, triggers - you also need triggers on Customer Master, to deal with deletions and updates to Location.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**:- As far as I know, there is no possible way to check constraint using a select statement. However for your case you can use a simple select query with where clause as given below

```
select * from A 
where somecolumn not in 
( select somecolumn from B where <condition for B> )
```

For your query, assuming you have sno as foreignkey in B -

```
select somedata from A
where someforeignKey = ( select sno from B where sno = 55 )
```

Comment: -1,. Both do no define check constraints. Granted, the OP does not seem to know what he wants to ask, but these are pretty much normal filter clauses, not check constraints.

Comment: @TomTom - Yes, from the example query given by OP this is what I could come with. Currently have modified answer to add a note saying it is not possible to check constraint with select statement.